# Send Checkbox (Multiple) Value From Child Window to Parent Page (php)

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I have a pop-up window that has checkbox input. And I need to pass the value from child page to parent page.

When I checked 1 checkbox, its value passed to parent, but when I check 2 boxes,  the only value that passes is the last box.
If you still don't get it, here's the example:

When I check

✔ A

✔ B

The only value that passed to parent page is B. And I need to pass all of the checked boxes to the parent page (A and B).

The value from child window to parent page is already successfully passed. Here's my code

In HTML (checkbox file):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.close();     
    opener.document.getElementById("page_iframe_id").contentWindow.document.page_iframe.submit();
</script>

<input class="check_custom" type="checkbox" name="id_institution" id="" value="<?=$model['id']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="id_hidden[]" value="<?=$model['id']?>">
```

I expect all of the checkbox's value passed to parent page so in text box parent page the value shown. Thank you.

Comment: Are you giving the checkboxes a different `id`? If you don't then the second checkbox just overwrites the first one and that would be why you always only get the last checkbox back.

Comment: isn't it that your name attribute in checkbox needs to have `[]`? `id_institution[]` like so

Comment: @DirkScholten the number of the checkbox is based from the database. but maybe you right about the overwrite :/

Comment: @Ghost should i change it to an array id_institution[]?